# how to get innerhtml close to a span id javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello guys i am having a problem i am creating a google chrome extension that can exctract some infromation from a website and saving them on a txt file.

The issue is that i want to exctract a innerhtml data close to a span ID this is the code i need to be able to exctract:

```
        <tr class="gridRow_even">
        <td class="fieldLabel_150">
            Date
        </td>
        <td>


            <span id="123"></span>
            12/20

        </td>
    </tr>
```

What i want to save is 12/20 on the txt usually i do get element by ID but in this case i have no idea how to get it i tried also doing this using jquery this:

var DT = $("td:contains(/)")

But it gives me object object when i try to save as txt the data exctracted.I have no idea how to do this i am getting crazy please help!!!

Comment: You could try throwing 12/20 into a <span> with an id or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const text = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('td'), el => el.querySelector('span#a123'))[0].innerText;
console.log(text);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="gridRow_even">
    <td class="fieldLabel_150">Date</td>
    <td>
      <span id="a123"></span>
      12/20
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Before the explanation, two quick notes about this example:

- `document.querySelector('td')` doesn't appear to work unless it's in a proper table. It's likely your real example is in a `<table>`, so it's a moot point. If it's not, you'll need to come up with a slightly different method of finding it (which could be the topic of another answer).
- `123` is not a valid id. An id must begin with a letter. Again, your real target is probably named fine. If it really does start with a number, use `el.querySelector('span[id=123]')` instead.

As for the code, basically use `document.querySelectorAll('td')` to get all of the `td` elements (if they're in a specific table, use that as well, like `'#tableId td'`).

Then, I used `Array.prototype.filter()` to filter all of the `td` elements, looking for any that contained the span we want to find. Had to use `Array.prototype.filter.call()` because the result of `document.querySelectorAll()` is actually a `NodeList`, which is array-like, but not an actual array.

Once I have filtered, I just get the first element from the filter and get it's `innerText`.

If there might be more than one `td` that has the `span` in a page, use `.map(el => el.innerText)` instead of `[0].innerText` to create an array of all of the values instead.

An alternative would also be to find all of the `<span>` elements, then loop through and get each of their `parentNode` elements. This would require though that the `<span>` is a direct child of the `<td>`, so may be less flexible depending on your real use case.

```js
const text = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('span#a123'), el => el.parentNode)[0].innerText;
console.log(text);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="gridRow_even">
    <td class="fieldLabel_150">Date</td>
    <td>
      <span id="a123"></span>
      12/20
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you know for sure it'll only ever be one span, you can use this instead:

```js
const text = document.querySelector('span#a123').parentNode.innerText;
console.log(text);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="gridRow_even">
    <td class="fieldLabel_150">Date</td>
    <td>
      <span id="a123"></span>
      12/20
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: great solution i used and it doesnt gives also the result as <span id="a123"></span>       12/20      but only 12/20 perfect thanks alot for everything guys

Comment: const text = document.querySelector('span#a123').parentNode.innerText;

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the expected output

```
$("span#123").parent().text();
```

Simple Javascript

```
document.getElementById("123").parentNode.innerText;
```

Comment: Seems a good idea  do you know anyway in normal javascript? becuase its giving me problems

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
var desired_innerHTML = document.getElementById('123').parentElement.innerHTML;
```

jQuery

```
var desired_innerHTML = $('#123').parent().html();
```

Answer (score 0):

**12/20** is a text node. You can filter the result of [.contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) by [.nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).

```js
var DT = $("td:contains(/)").contents().filter(function(idx, ele) {
    return ele.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && ele.textContent.trim().length != 0;
});
console.log('Txt: ' + DT.text().trim())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="gridRow_even">
        <td class="fieldLabel_150">
            Date
        </td>
        <td>


            <span id="123"></span>
            12/20

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gridRow_even">
        <td class="fieldLabel_150">
            Date
        </td>
        <td>


            <span id="xxx"></span>
           

        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```